# Can not install Appium/Node Js on MacOSX

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, appium

I have problem with Appium Installation on Mac OSX.

```
brew uninstall node

brew install node
```

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using brew postinstall node

```
brew postinstall node

Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Should I use here with "SUDO" ??

```
sudo brew postinstall node
```

best regards,
koko

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this forum](http://forums.webhook.com/t/cant-get-node-to-install-on-latest-osx-mavericks-resolved/109/17), if you scroll down to the bottom... the steps should be:

```
brew uninstall node
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
rm -r /Users/username/.npm/ # replace username with your user
brew install node
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Node.js

Change owner using "sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm"

Install appium using 
"npm install -g appium"